# how to populate textbox depending up on combobox value?

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I have this scenario where I have a combo box name contract, row source type is table/query. Now on the text box I would like to display the name of the person, telephone, mobile, fax, address. A contract belongs to many persons so I would like to count the contract in a label if possible otherwise textbox is fine. Suppose the user choose contract from combobox i.e. NSW college, now I would like to display the details of the person in text boxes and I would also like to count the number of contractor at the same time. I have got a single table for this. I apologize if i didn't make myself clear.

The code i used so far is

```
Private Sub cmbContractSite_AfterUpdate()
Me.txtName = Me.cmbContractSite.column(1)

me.txtPhoneNo=Me.cmbContractSite.column(2)

.

.
End Sub
```

for counting

```
Private Sub cmbContractSite_AfterUpdate()
Me.txtCount = Me.cmbContractSite.ListCount
End Sub
```

but didn't work at all

Any help please?

Comment: Can you confirm if this is WinForms, WPF, or ASP.NET?

Comment: You can't access the column property directly from a combobox. You need to access the columns of the datasource of your combobox. If you provide more code (specifically pertaining to the datasource), I can help you a bit more.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Contract_Site has a query as row source i.e. SELECT tbl_Contract.Contract, tbl_Contract.Industry_Group FROM tbl_Contract ORDER BY tbl_Contract.Contract, tbl_Contract.Industry_Group; I would like to create a combobox of contract_site so that whenever user chooses a particular contract all other fields have to populate dynamically. But i have got everything in single table. I have not written anymore code. all i did was i create textbox for each records in form. i create combobox for contract_site by wizard and write the above code to populate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `ControlSource` of the textbox to the following, having changed the name of the field your are counting, the table-name, etc.

```
=DCount("StaffID","[tblStaff]","Office='" & [Combo0].[Column](3) & "'")
```

This counts the number of StaffID fields in the table tblStaff, where the Office matches the currently selected value in column 3 of the combobox. So when I select a staff member from the combobox it displays a count of all staff who are at the same Office as this person.

Setting the ControlSource of the textbox to

```
=[Combo0].[ListCount]
```

displays the total count of all items in the combobox.

**Added** These database functions are very fussy about syntax. In the Access Help system it suggests that the field-name should have square brackets, but not the table-name. This is incorrect, it is the other way round.

Comment: Andy Thank you for your response but when i put DCount() function in controlsource of combobox. it will not allow me to select new record. All i want is whenever i choose any contract i want to fill text boxes with rest of the detail, Apparently, i am able to get the record by using DLookup() but it shows one record only. I would like to navigate the records depending up on the combo box value and i would like to count that particular contract as well, which means how many contract i have and who are the person involve in text boxes. Please any help. I am still working out with this.

Comment: You don't put the DCOUNT as the control-source of the combobox; that won't work. I'm setting it as the control-source for a textbox on the form, to display a count based on the item selected in the combobox. Re-read my answer.

Comment: Sorry, i wrote =DCount("Contract_Site","tbl_Worksite_Contact_All", "Contract_Site=' " & [cmbContract].[Column](3) & "  ' ") as a control source of Text16 but it always shows 0 records whatever i select in combo box. i am counting based on contract name and counting the number of contract which is in column 3 of tbl_Worksite_Contact_All.

Comment: Enclose the table name in square brackets "[tbl_Worksite_Contact_All]" - these database functions are very fussy.

Comment: You also have extra spaces enclosed between the apostrophes ' won't work '.